# Override ActiveRecord find() method with two behaviors

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

How can override ActiveRecord `find()` method with two behaviors?
I am using two behaviors in model and each of one has override the find() method.

Thanks

Comment: explain better .. you question adding the code you are trying to use .. override  is simple but what do you mean with " with two behaviors"

Comment: @scaisEdge a good description of my mean is [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/70120-using-behaviors/) i had exactly this issue